# Find DPI of an Image

Tags: python, image, dpi

I have an image with no horizontal or vertical resolution in its Properties/ Detail. I try to find dpi with `PIL.Image`. Like this code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(image_path)
print(im.info['dpi'])
```

But it said `KeyError: 'dpi'`. Please help me to find the dpi of [this image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/183721930@N03/shares/t75TR7) (this image is larger than 2MB so I can't upload in here, sorry that, please click into the link to get the image)

Comment: image doesn't have to have `dpi` in file. And it doesn't need it to display it. `dpi` (dot per inch) can be useful when you want to print it on printer but then `dpi` depend how big image you will print - how many inches it will have on paper. And then you can get image size in pixel and divide by inches to get its dpi on paper.

Comment: BTW: [300 DPI, 72 DPI, What is DPI and how does it work? Find out the truth...](https://snapshop.cam/dpi/)